# Spring MVC request mapping and PathVariable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is possible map following url in Spring MVC, using @PathVariable anotation?

```
/download/253/path/to/file/name.ext
```

I tried to following pattern: `/download/{intVar}/{fileLocation}`, but requests failed with 400 HTTP error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Reference
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex

In your case, it would be as below

```
@RequestMapping("/download/{intVar}/**{fileLocation:.+}")
```

Comment: No mapping found for HTTP request. I tried to use {fileLocation:.*}, but it is same.

Comment: Would you mind trying "/download/{intVar}/*{fileLocation:.+}"?

Comment: Of course, I meant `@RequestMapping("/download/{intVar}/{fileLocation:.*}")`

Comment: One last try please: "/download/{intVar}/**{fileLocation:.+}". Please check if this works.

Comment: Your answer is not complete. You left out configuration of `ContentNegotiationManager`.